locust task with multipart files request
The following multipart curl request works fine:
curl -X 'POST' 'http://123.123.123.123:8080/myendpoint' -F 'input_json=@inputdata.json' -F 'config=@config.yml' -F 'format=png' --output result.png

I am trying to convert this request into a locust 'task.py' file to test a server as following:
class ServingClient(locust.HttpUser):
    wait_time = locust.between(0.8, 0.9)
    @locust.task
    def predict(self):
        response =self.client.post(self.url,
                                   files={'input_json':json.dumps(self.input_json),
                                          'config':yaml.dump(self.config),'format':'png'
                                         })
    def on_start(self):
        with open('inputdata.json']) as f:
            self.input_json = json.load(f)
        with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
            self.config = yaml.safe_load(f)

        self.url = '{}/myendpoint'.format(
            self.environment.host)

and then run the following terminal command in the dir of locust file including json and yaml files:
locust -f task.py --headless --host http://123.123.123.123:8080

but all (100%) of request fail. and  the following error report is print upon terminated the terminal:
Error report
# occurrences      Error                                                                                               
------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7                  POST /myendpoint: HTTPError('422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for url: /myendpoint')

I am wondering what is the issue or if there is anyway to print the curl request literal inside the task.py to debug it?

Hi! Have a look at https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html#print-http-communication
